# What is codegolf.xyz?

Tags: support

Yesterday google turned up "codegolf.xyz".  It seems to be an up-to-date mirror of codegolf.se but not exactly.  For instance, if I go to the first question and click "more comments", it doesn't show me more comments.  Is this a legitimate mirror or is it something else?

Comment: Also, we cannot sign up/log in

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Original Intent

I created this domain a while back when there were many new challenges involving some kind of parsing on the PPCG site. For a while, only some sites redirected to actual PPCG sites and originally, I planned to create online interpreters for various exotic languages used on PPCG.

### Now

- Now, many shorter domains exists, including ppcg.lol (and .ga) etc.
- Dennis' TIO now provides the interpreter functionality.
- As kind of a PHP exercise, I rewrote the site. It's *not* a mirror, but a proxy.

The source for the proxy can be found here: https://github.com/minxomat/codegolf.xyz

Thus, the "site" that appears on the proxy can't be out of date, since it is re-fetched (with occasional caching) every time one visits. Login and a bunch of not-PPCG site features don't work and this *is* intentional. One should *never* input credentials through *any* kind of proxy. codegolf.xyz has an experimental HTTPS mode, where every resource is rewritten to be fetched over HTTPS (which currently has a bug where some links are forced to https even if they don't support it).

Trivia: The cg.xyz site usually loads faster than the actual site due to some caching shenanigans. My use for this site is as a playground for DNS-level caching and compression. About 1,6k organic, unique (non-search-engine) users use this proxy every month.

Comment: If anyone has €225/year to spare, we could also register http://pp.cg/ for something even shorter.

Comment: This seems like a) there should be some notice that you are not on Stack Exchange, and b) a robots.txt telling crawlers not to crawl the site. Otherwise, this is no less than a [SCRAPER](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do), as codegolf.xyz is taking credit for the posts without linking back to SE.

Comment: This is illegal screen scraping. You just [confuse people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283291/login-link-from-codegolf-xyz-not-working-redirecting-to-codegolf-xyz-users-http) and cause more harm than good in my opinion. Better  shut this thing down before it cause  more harm.